# void is not assignable to type value User Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am calling a JSON file using rx/js Observable.

Service

```
constructor(private http: Http){

}

 getUserById():Observable<User[]> {

let url = this.mockData;
let header = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

return this.http.get(url)
    .map((res:Response) =><User[]>res.json())
    .do(data => console.log("User Data: "+JSON.stringify(data)))
    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error) || "Mock Data Error get by role")
};
```

component:

```
    @Input() users: User[] = [];

        userTemp: User[] = [];

getUserById(userId){

        this._searchService.getUserById()
            .filter(users => {
                for(let user of users){
                    if(user.userName === userId){
                        this.userTemp.push(user);
                    }}});

        return this.userTemp;

    }
```

under `users => {` says when I hover over it `(Users: Users[]) => void is not assignable) => boolean.`

I know there is a small detail I am missing but I am not sure where it is. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

------------------------------update 1--------------------------
Trying this now but and it compiles but doesn't work.

```
this._searchService.getUserById()
            ._do(users => {
                for(let user of this.users){
                    if(user.id == userId){
                        this.userTemp.push(user);
                    }
                }
            });
```

---------------------Update 2--------------------------
I got some advice from the posts below and now I am trying to do it like this, but it is rendering nothing and giving no errors.

In component:

```
@Input() users: IUser[] = [];
```

Method being called in component:

```
case 'role':
          this.users = this.getUserByRole(this.role);
          console.log(this.role);
          break;
```

method in component:

```
 getUserByRole(role){

        this._searchService.getUsers()
            .subscribe(users => {
                for(let user of users) {
                    if(user.role == role){
                        this.users.push(user);
                    }}});

        return this.users;
    }
```

Service method:

```
getUsers(): Observable<IUser[]> {
        let users = this.http
            .get(this.url)
            .map(res => res.json());
        return users;
    }
```

In the console it will print whatever I put in the input box and I confirmed the `url` for the http call is valid.

I am trying to do it like this so all I need to do is change the http url to have headers and a real url later without have to change to much.

--------------Update 3----------------------

In the HTML I have:

```
 <td>{{data.role | async}}</td>
```

method in component:

```
getUserByRole(role){

        return this._searchService.getUsers()
            .map(data => {
                return data.filter((x:any) => x.role == role)
            });
    }
```

Field:

```
 @Input() users: Observable<IUser[]>;
```

Calling the method:

```
case 'role':
         console.log(this.getUserByRole(this.role));
         this.users = this.getUserByRole(this.role);
         console.log(this.users);
         break;
```

error:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

In my searchService I am now looking at doing it this way but still not working:

```
 findUserByRole(user: IUser) {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                data => {

                }
            );
    }
```

Comment: When you put a `console.log(this.users);` just before you return it, what do you see in the log?

Comment: @echonax before and after just renders `[ ]`

Comment: Do you know how async operations work? Or have you read AJT_82's answer carefully?

Comment: @echonax Yes I did and AJT made a very nice example. However I am unable to get it to work. The end goal is to not call `getUsers` all the time. I might only get one and the backend will only send one but I still need an array on my end to loop through in my HTML file just in case. I get that filter will do that for me so I am implementing that now. Please see update 3.

Comment: @echonax if I put `*ngFor='let data of users | async'` I get an error saying `data.filter is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT based on updates:**

Not entirely sure, what you are trying to achieve with: `<td>{{data.role | async}}</td>`, but if you want to filter users based on a specific role using async pipe would be to declare `users` as an Observable like you have. When you want to filter, have your switch statement (like you have):

```ts
case 'role':
      this.users = this.getUserByRole(this.role);
      break;
```

and in this method you return an observable of the filtered array

```ts
getUserByRole(role){
    return this._searchService.getUsers()
        .map(data => {
            return data.filter((x:any) => x.role == role)
        });
}
```

which you then can use together with async pipe, which displays the users which have the filtered values from your switch-case, whatever that filter value might be. In this case we have filtered above based on a role value.

```ts
<div *ngFor="let user of users | async">
```

### [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/kRG4pXUob8lUQsbLhNVb?p=preview)

**Update 2:**

Now seeing your JSON, the problem should be that your array is in an object named `data`. You want the array from the response, so you need to extract that array from the object, so change your mapping a bit:

```ts
return this.http.get(url)
    .map((res:Response) =><User[]>res.json().data) // here! Extract the array from the object "data"
    .do(data => console.log("User Data: "+JSON.stringify(data)))
    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error) || "Mock Data Error get by role")
};
```

---

**Original post:**

`filter` actually does the filtering for you, you do not need to iterate the response. Unfortunately I do not see that you are able to return `userTemp` other than as an observable in your filtering. You actually have to subscribe to it and assign the values from the filter to your `userTemp`, the following will always return `undefined` as you are returning the array outside the callback:

```ts
getUserById(userId){
   this._searchService.getUserById()
     .map(users => {
        ......
     });
     return this.userTemp; // data has not been assigned yet, when you return it.
}
```

This is just how it works. You need to do manipulate your data inside the callback! Here is some more info: [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

But back to your code, You can map several times, so here you would use `map` together with `filter` to get the data you want:

```ts
getUserById(userId) {
 return this.service.getUsers()
   .map(data => {
     return data.filter((x:any) => x.userName == userId)
   });
}
```

So this returnes an observable to where you need it.

But as said, AFAIK you cannot return the userTemp as a plain JS array.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I been trying to get this to work but it seems there is still something I am missing. Please see update 2.

Comment: This is so frustrating. I am doing exactly that to which you are doing in your update. Only different is using `@Input() users: Observable<IUser[]>;` and not `@Input() users: any;` but that didn't seem to matter. I am getting an error saying: `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. `

Comment: Could you perhaps fork my plunker and make a MCV, I'd be happy to take a look :) Somewhere, something has to be wrong, since it doesn't work. Try and reproduce the issue in a plunker and I'll take a look. Is there btw a reason why you use `@Input()` here?

Comment: Maybe stupid, but have you made sure there is data coming in? That error can be thrown if there's nothing to iterate. The other option that I can think of that it's simply not an array, but "something else". Take a close look at your incoming data. Somewhere there lies the issue, pretty sure ;)

Comment: Could you add a sample of your JSON?

Comment: You are trying to iterate an Object `data`. You need to adjust the map in your service and extract the array from your json, so: `.map((res:Response) =><User[]>res.json().data)` I'll edit my answer. Then your problem should be solved I think ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139607/discussion-between-drew1208-and-ajt-82).

Answer (score 0):

The callback for `.filter` requires that you return a `boolean`, but you're returning nothing (aka `void`). You need either need to return a `boolean` or use a different method.

Comment: I need a list returned, any suggestions.